# Saving a ServerSocket to a Database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sockets

I am wondering if it is possible to save a variable type "ServerSocket" to a database, and how would I do this? I know that I can save strings using "TEXT" and images using "BLOB", when I create my table in an SQLite Database? but how can I save a SeverSocket type?

If this can't be done is there another way to save a ServerSocket variable so that when my app re-starts it remembers that value of my ServerSocket variable? Like in Shared Preferences, but I know Shared Preferences cannot do this.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. There is no difficulty about creating a new ServerSocket with the same port number every time your program starts, and there is no way to persist sockets or server sockets or input streams or output streams or threads or a large number of other things either.

Comment: @EJP I get that this question doesn't make sense from your view, and maybe doesn't make sense in Android in general. Sorry for the bad post. I posted my full question at this link, so maybe you can see where this question came from and what I am stuck with.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38214886/serversocket-is-null-when-broadcastreceiver-gets-new-intent

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to store the instance?  I would think it makes more sense to store the property values like port, address, etc. and properly init the socket with the stored values. Just my $.02 worth.

Comment: Sorry for the bad post. I posted my full question at this link, so maybe you can see where this question came from and what I am stuck with.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38214886/serversocket-is-null-when-broadcastreceiver-gets-new-intent